# Cannot redeclare class mdb2_error in Pear MDB2 package

Tags: php, pear, mdb2

I haven't install pear in my PC,instead I download the packages and unzip them to "libs" dictionary in my web-app.the structure of dictionary of my web-app is roughly like this:

```
web-app
  +-/backend
    +-/libs
      +-/peardb
        +-pear.php
        +-pear5.php
        +-mdb2.php
        +-/mdb2
```

The application works fine in my two PCs,but throws "Cannot redeclare class mdb2_error" error while it running in virtual host.

Comment: You'll probably need to share the full error message, at least. Also, by your "two PCs" do you mean Windows machines? That is, what is your specific local setup? Finally, I assume you mean a virtual hosting provider when you say "in virtual host". In some cases it's useful to know which one.

Answer (score 3):

Using `include_once` / `require_once` can usually solve this problem.